# Determine which source row is returned for SQL MAX() function

Tags: mysql, sql, max

Say I have the following table:

```
+---------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| book_id | book_name                           | isbn_no     | cate_id | aut_id | pub_id | dt_of_pub  | pub_lang | no_page | book_price |
+---------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| BK001   | Introduction to Electrodynamics     | 0000979001  | CA001   | AUT001 | P003   | 2001-05-08 | English  |     201 |      85.00 |
| BK002   | Understanding of Steel Construction | 0000979002  | CA002   | AUT002 | P001   | 2003-07-15 | English  |     300 |     105.50 |
| BK003   | Guide to Networking                 | 0000979003  | CA003   | AUT003 | P002   | 2002-09-10 | Hindi    |     510 |     200.00 |
| BK004   | Transfer  of Heat and Mass          | 0000979004  | CA002   | AUT004 | P004   | 2004-02-16 | English  |     600 |     250.00 |
| BK005   | Conceptual Physics                  | 0000979005  | CA001   | AUT005 | P006   | 2003-07-16 | NULL     |     345 |     145.00 |
| BK006   | Fundamentals of Heat                | 0000979006  | CA001   | AUT006 | P005   | 2003-08-10 | German   |     247 |     112.00 |
| BK007   | Advanced 3d Graphics                | 0000979007  | CA003   | AUT007 | P002   | 2004-02-16 | Hindi    |     165 |      56.00 |
| BK008   | Human Anatomy                       | 0000979008  | CA005   | AUT008 | P006   | 2001-05-17 | German   |      88 |      50.50 |
| BK009   | Mental Health Nursing               | 0000979009  | CA005   | AUT009 | P007   | 2004-02-10 | English  |     350 |     145.00 |
| BK010   | Fundamentals of Thermodynamics      | 0000979010  | CA002   | AUT010 | P007   | 2002-10-14 | English  |     400 |     225.00 |
| BK011   | The Experimental Analysis of Cat    | 0000979011  | CA004   | AUT011 | P005   | 2007-06-09 | French   |     225 |      95.00 |
| BK012   | The Nature  of World                | 0000979012  | CA004   | AUT005 | P008   | 2005-12-20 | English  |     350 |      88.00 |
| BK013   | Environment a Sustainable Future    | 0000979013  | CA004   | AUT012 | P001   | 2003-10-27 | German   |     165 |     100.00 |
| BK014   | Concepts in Health                  | 0000979014  | CA005   | AUT013 | P004   | 2001-08-25 | NULL     |     320 |     180.00 |
| BK015   | Anatomy & Physiology                | 0000979015  | CA005   | AUT014 | P008   | 2000-10-10 | Hindi    |     225 |     135.00 |
| BK016   | Networks and Telecommunications     | 00009790_16 | CA003   | AUT015 | P003   | 2002-01-01 | French   |      95 |      45.00 |
+---------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
```

My query is :

```
SELECT cate_id, MAX( book_price)
FROM book_mast
GROUP BY cate_id;
```

it returns :

```
+---------+-----------------+
| cate_id | MAX(book_price) |
+---------+-----------------+
| CA001   |          145.00 | 
| CA002   |          250.00 | 
| CA003   |          200.00 | 
| CA004   |          100.00 | 
| CA005   |          180.00 | 
+---------+-----------------+
```

Now say for first record - CA001 with max book price 145.

1. How do I determine that it is Conceptual Physics with book_id=BK005?
2. What happens if there are two records matching same maximum value?

(this problem is part of a big view which I'm trying to resolve, sorry for shamelessly copying the example from https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-max-with-group-by.php. This is just for explaining problem)

Comment: Searching for "mysql greatest-n-per-group" might yield some good reading. This is a specific case of n=1, which can be solved with MAX. There are other options as well.

Comment: Specify MySQL version.

Comment: *What happens if there are two records matching same maximum value?* That is YOU ONLY who may say what MUST happen in this case - either all of them or one of them selected by some additional criteria (the former by alphabetic order, for example) must be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use group by to get the max price for each cate_id, and then inner join with original table to get the book_id

```
SELECT a.cate_id, a.book_price as 'MAX(book_price)', a.book_id
FROM book_mast a
inner join 
(
    SELECT x.cate_id, MAX(x.book_price) AS max_price
    FROM book_mast x
    GROUP BY x.cate_id;
) b
on a.cate_id = b.cate_id AND a.book_price = b.max_price
```

Comment: As with other answers, this can return multiple copies of cate_id for the same max book price. The OP asks about this scenario (although does not specify an appropriate result). Similar comments on other answers.

Comment: I do not understand why is this accepted answer when it is same as the one from @scaisEdge ?

Answer (score 2):

You need  a join  between the aggreated result and the original values  based on the  aggregated  results

```
select m.* from book_mast m
inner join  (
    SELECT cate_id, MAX( book_price) max_price
    FROM book_mast
    GROUP BY cate_id

    ) t on t.cate_id = m.cate_id and t.max_price = m.book_price
```

Comment: Note: This can return multiple rows for each cate_id if multiple rows the same cate_id have the same book_price. The expected behavior in this case has not been defined.

Comment: @Strawberry  . correct  ..  added  the table ref .. thanks

Comment: @Strawberry  I guess you have your own way of processing the comments but despite having been dealing with them for a long time I don't understand it .. anyway .. thanks

Comment: OK - VBoka fixed the error an hour ago;  right after I commented.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT bm1.book_id
       , bm1.book_name
       , bm1.cate_id
       , bm1.book_price
FROM book_mast bm1
where bm1.book_price = (SELECT MAX( bm2.book_price )
                        FROM book_mast bm2
                        where bm2.cate_id = bm1.cate_id);
```

Here is a small demo for his example: [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=69395b0d3c2d18d362097e3349e890c6)

Comment: This might also yield more than one result per cate_id if two books were to have the same price

Comment: Many SQL query planners will (thankfully) turn this into a join instead of treating it as a dependent subquery. I recommend using explicit joins in general to not have to rely on such implementation details .. for example, I work in SQL Server and have no idea how MySQL would treat this :)

Comment: The `GROUP BY` in the subquery is unnecessary.